# Are remotely operated (SSH) printouts in python scripts blocking?

Tags: python, ssh, tcp, stdout

Suppose I ssh from computer `A` into computer `B` and run a python script on `B` which is something like the following:

```
...
print "Hello World"
foo()
...
```

Will function `foo()`:

1. Be executed immediately following the `print ...` statement?
2. Or will it be executed after the output of the `print ...` statement is visible in the terminal of computer `A`?

Put differently, can I speed up a python script operated remotely via ssh via removing a lot of printouts the script might have?

Perhaps this is just a fundamental flaw in my understanding of stdout/ssh/etc. but I couldn't find an answer; enlighten me!

Comment: In the sense you are thinking of, probably not. There's probably a buffer between your Python script and the network socket connected to your machine; you write to standard output, and `sshd` transfers those bytes to the socket buffer. As long as the remote network stack can pass those bytes onto the network faster than `sshd` can fill the buffer, your program will not block.